# SharePoint Search - Crawls for All Document Versions?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

we're running a copy of MOSS 2007 and we're not entirely certain if the Search functions index all versions of the document stored under MOSS. Thoughts from the crowd? Thanks!

Comment: @tekiegreg: Out of curiosity, how would this be useful?

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard of previous versions being searched. A simple experiment should sort this out definitively, you will have to differentiate "current" editing versions of a page/document from the published version. Different users will have visibility of the edited version compared to read only viewers.